# query for woocommerce quickview and oceanwp theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The probleme : on a woocommerce multivendor website using ocean wp theme, when a logged in user click on a product quickview button the query is altered with author = connected user id, then the jumping window is empty...except for admin and product's owner. The probleme is observed only for the quickview.

Here are the recorded query:
Loggedin customer: (doesn't work)

[0] => SELECT   db_posts.* FROM db_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND db_posts.ID = 159 AND **db_posts.post_author IN (7)**  AND db_posts.post_type = 'product'  ORDER BY db_posts.post_date DESC
[1] => 0.00043106079101562
[2] => do_action('wp_ajax_oceanwp_product_quick_view'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, OceanWP_WooCommerce_Config->product_quick_view_ajax, wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
[3] => 1592946063.1666
[4] => Array

Unlogged customer: (work perfectly!)

[0] => SELECT   db_posts.* FROM db_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND db_posts.ID = 159 AND db_posts.post_type = 'product'  ORDER BY db_posts.post_date DESC
[1] => 0.00040388107299805
[2] => do_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_oceanwp_product_quick_view'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, OceanWP_WooCommerce_Config->product_quick_view_ajax, wp, WP->main, WP->query_posts, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
[3] => 1592946202.7735
[4] => Array
Part of the query is set up with wp() function in woocommerce-config.php file in oceanwp theme folder:

```
    /**
     * Quick view ajax.
     *
     * @since 1.5.0
     */
    public static function product_quick_view_ajax() {
        if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['product_id'] ) ) {
            die();
        }

        $product_id = intval( $_REQUEST['product_id'] );

        // wp_query for the product.
        wp( 'p=' . $product_id . '&post_type=product' );

        ob_start();

        get_template_part( 'woocommerce/quick-view-content' );

        echo ob_get_clean();

        die();
    }
```

I am trying to remove the author parameter from the query.
Please advise. Many thanks